# Can we use custom shaders in DOSBox?

Tags: dosbox

I would like to know if we can add custom shaders to DOSBox, just like how we add [GLSL or Slang shaders to RetroArch](https://www.retroarch.com/?page=shaders)?

Comment: what game.....?